# Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following component in angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-status',
  templateUrl: './status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./status.component.css']
})
export class StatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
      };
    }
  }

}
```

i'm retrieving the following error from the compiler

ERROR in src/app/components/status/status.component.ts(16,16): error TS2339: Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Altough the compilation is success and all works as expected.

Should i ignore the error?

Comment: Question aside, the way you are doing things, you are not following "Angular way".

Comment: I agree with @Plochie. You'd be better off adopting the angular way to add handlers. The code as-is looks like trying to hang on to an older and more fragile way of writing web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user above mentioned, you have to cast it to HTMLElement, but inside the for loop. I don't have reputation to comment, thats why i answered again.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        HTMLElement(acc[i]).onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
      };
    }
  }
```

Or I would rather recommend using the "addEventListener" function, if you use "document.getElementsByClassName" anyways.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I solved through other way, but with the eventListener seems more correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to `HTMLElement`

```
const acc: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion') as HTMLElement;
```

Comment: if change to this, it not works, error appears Property 'length' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: Function `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list. The short way is to assume there's one element, e.g. `const acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion')[0] as HTMLElement`. It's "ok" but you run the risk of a runtime exception. You can split this into stages and first get the list, then check if there is an element (`.length > 0`) and then cast with `elements[0] as HTMLElement`.